# 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, google-analytics-sdk

Trying to compile my project after adding some pods. While compiling it gives below error

> 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Podfile.lock snippet

```
- FirebaseCore (5.1.1):
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 5.2)
      - FirebaseDynamicLinks (3.0.2):
        - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 5.1)
      - FirebaseInAppMessaging (0.11.0):
        - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 5.1)
        - FirebaseCore (~> 5.1)
        - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.2)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.0)
      - FirebaseInstanceID (3.2.1):
        - FirebaseCore (~> 5.1)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
      - FirebaseMessaging (3.1.0):
        - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
        - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 5.2)
        - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
      - FirebaseRemoteConfig (3.0.1):
        - FirebaseABTesting (~> 2.0)
        - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 5.1)
        - FirebaseCore (~> 5.1)
        - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.2)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 5.2)"
        - Protobuf (~> 3.5)
      - Google/Analytics (2.0.4):
        - Google/Core
        - GoogleAnalytics (~> 3.12)
      - Google/Core (2.0.4):
        - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.0)
        - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.0)
        - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
        - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.1)
```

Comment: seems to be related with this issue https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/394

Comment: Have a look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246350/firebasecore-lexical-or-preprocessor-issue/55285806#55285806) to see what worked for me.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389295/5572214

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the Podfile, change `Google/Analytics` to `GoogleAnalytics`. The Google pod is deprecated and not compatible with recent Firebase versions.

An alternative, but not recommended workaround, could be to lock the Firebase version to something less than 5.5.

UPDATE: June 2021: There is a Crashlytics podspec bug that can also cause this issue. The workaround is to explicitly add `GoogleUtilities/Environment` to the Podfile or move `use_frameworks!` to the top of the Podfile. Details in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8137. The issue will be fixed in the upcoming Firebase 8.3.0 release.

Comment: Are you able to make a shareable example? Or reproduce with a Firebase quickstart? https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios

Comment: I have created a sample project. Please try building it.
https://github.com/phoenixroy/PodsTest

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample. I see what's happening and will update the answer.

Comment: In my case the dependency that was causing it was Google/SignIn, changed to GoogleSignIn and it's working!

Comment: In my case deleting the pods folder and reinstalling the pods via "pod install" command fixed the issue

Answer (score 15):

Problem fixed for me by following steps:

1. Clean the project
2. Close the Xcode
3. Delete derived data
4. If you have already installed the POD, kindly delete the “.xcworkspace” & “Podfile.lock” files
5. Install pod again
6. Open “.xcworkspace” and Run

Answer (score 10):

Running `pod update` fixed this for me

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

1. Delete the pod files related to Google and Firebase
2. Install pods via "`pod install`" command

If pod file contains below pods, update those pods

```
Google/Analytics to GoogleAnalytics
Google/SignIn to GoogleSignIn
```

`Google/Analytics` and `Google/SignIn` are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting Pods folder and reinstalling the pods again will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this plugin :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support --save
```

After go to platform/ios and run :
 pod update

Answer (score -1):

- In the podfile, install all pods after uncomment `use_frameworks!`.
- If you already installed pods then remove pods, and install again after uncomment `use_frameworks`

Answer (score -1):

As simple as that

- comment the pod
- pod install
- uncomment the pod (Make sure there is not version added to pod)
- pod install

There you go.

Answer (score -1):

None of the answers listed here worked for me.

The solution that worked for me is:

1. Clean the project and close the Xcode
2. Clean the pod using command `pod clean`
3. Install the pod again using `pod install`
4. Open the project and build that one, it worked