# FirebaseCore Lexical or preprocessor issue

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am having an issue in compiling my project with firebase. This issue started the minuted I updated all my firebase pods. Ever since I updated the pods I have been getting this error

> Lexical or preprocessor issue

and then when I go to what the error is it says this

> 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Has anyone faced this problem or have any idea how to fix it?

I have tried uninstalling and installing, I have tried changing the scheme and rebuilding, I have tried cleaning and building and nothing has worked.

I have included a picture of what I can see in Xcode.

[image]

Here is what my podfile looks like

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925881/googleutilities-gulappenvironmentutil-h-file-not-found)

Comment: Yeah that solution didn't work

Comment: Same problem here :@

Comment: how did you fix this?

Comment: that's a big podfile

Answer (score 1):

Change the Podfile from `pod 'Google/SignIn'` to `pod 'GoogleSignIn'`.

source: issue [2100](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2100).

Comment: the reason is in every cause an outdated version of `GoogleUtilities` ...

Comment: im confused are you telling me to add that pod?

Comment: @BoJackson that screenshot is merely useless. a list of pods might enable someone to leave a better answer... because some pod might depend on an outdated version of `GoogleUtilities`, which lacks the `GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h` header.

Comment: okay so again do i add this pod, do i update google utilities, im generally lost

Comment: @BoJackson if you add it as text instead of a screenshot; it would be something one could copy & paste into an IDE... looking at things barely helps with dependency issues. there are at least 7 closed issue concerning that header file: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues?q=is%3Aissue+GULAppEnvironmentUtil+is%3Aclosed

Comment: what do you want me to add in text?

Comment: @BoJackson this would improve your chances to get an answer (I don't even have `OSX`); while opening a new issue on GitHub (incl. the pods as text) might also lead to an answer. this is a good example: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1266

Answer (score 1):

After reading many solutions, what worked for me was doing a pod update:

```
cd platforms/ios; pod update; cd ../..
```

That brought all the versions into line. Occams razor, I guess.